# Error not being thrown when missing this.name in JavaScript using includes function

Tags: javascript, error-handling

```js
class Speaker {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    get Message() {
        if (!this.message.includes(this.name)) {
            throw Error("message is missing speaker's name");
        }
        return this.message;
    }
    set Message(val) {
        let tmpMessage = val;
        if (!val.includes(this.name)) {
            tmpMessage = this.name + " " + val;
        }
        this.message = tmpMessage;
    }
}
const speaker = new Speaker();
speaker.Message = "hello";
console.log(speaker.Message);
```

I got this code from a book. I am confused as to why the  error is not being thrown when I run it, since in the book is states that it does. Instead I get **undefined Hello** Can someone shine some light on this?

Comment: Why should it throw an error? Step through the code (or/and add some `console.log()`s, e.g. `console.log(val.includes(this.name))`) and you will see why it works as it works.

Comment: no I see that it is working, but the error is not being thrown when I instantiate a new Speaker without the name. I got the error to be thrown if I do this in the `getter this.name == undefined` I'm thinking it is an error in the book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not throwing error because `!this.message.includes(this.name)` is not getting satisfied.

In your example,

```
speaker.Message = "hello";
```

When you called this, internally you are checking `!val.includes(this.name)`. Here `this.name` is `undefined` so, `!val.includes(this.name)` will be `true` and the message that gets saved is `undefined hello`.

And on calling

```
console.log(speaker.Message);
```

You are checking `!this.message.includes(this.name)`, here `this.name` is `undefined` and `this.message` is `undefined hello`.

Eventually `!this.message.includes(this.name)` will be `false`. Hence `this.message` is being returned which is `undefined hello` which is why the error is not being thrown.

```js
//!this.message.includes(this.name) --> 
//this condition gets evaluated like below, hence error is not thrown
console.log(!"undefined hello".includes(undefined));
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense. So perhaps I am misinterpreting the book or the example in the book is wrong. In the books example they provide a name, it was only me that removed the name to try to see if an error is being thrown, which in this case it was not and you explained why.

Comment: Happy to have helped you :-)